# "As was [past participle]" construction

Tags: as

Here is a sentence from *Robin Hood*:

> Because he did sell three times as much for one penny **as was sold by the other butchers.**

I do not understand "as was sold by the other butchers." Are the words "what is" missing between "as...was?" Should the sentence read:

> Because he did sell three times as much for one penny as what is sold by the other butchers.

Comment: First off it should be "...as what **was** sold..." to match the tense with the rest of the sentence. Second, you are correct that that is the *meaning,* but the original sentence is grammatically correct. (Or, well, that part of it is correct. As a whole it is a sentence *fragment.*)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why do we drop the word" what"?

Comment: I disagree that it should be _as what was sold_. We can say "I have twice as many sweets as you have." "For one penny, he sold three times as much as the other butchers did."

Comment: Yeah,  your sentence is another way to express the same meaning. But i want to know how to understand  the original words. As you said, your sentence can be turned into: He sold three times as much  for one penny as  did the other butchers.